# How to make chrome incognito mode default?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, private-browsing

I know you can add parameters on the shortcut. However in windows 7, the "pinned" applications. I cant seem to edit the parameters for a pinned app. I assume the pinned apps are stored as shortcuts somewhere within the user's directory, not sure where?

Answer (score 4):

Pinned item shortcuts are stored in `%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`.

But you don’t need to edit them there; you can right-click the entry in the Taskbar, then right-click the program’s icon in the context-menu (just above the pin entry, above the close entry) and select *Properties*. Then you can append the appropriate command-line arguments (in this case `--incognito`).

[image]